# Why this error message appears in matlab (Undefined variable "comm" or class "comm.BCHEncoder")?

Tags: matlab, encoder

I need to use BCHEncoder built in function in matlab, but matlab does not recognize it

I have a message called S, I want to encode it using BCHEncoder

```
S=randi([0 1],k,1);                                
enc = comm.BCHEncoder(n,k);   
% CodewordLength property set to N and the MessageLength property set to 
   K.                      
R=step(enc,S);
```

When this code run, this error message appears( Undefined variable "comm" or class "comm.BCHEncoder". )

Comment: I use matlab R2019a

Comment: Check if you have communication toolbox: `license('test', 'communication_toolbox')`

Comment: yes, it exists.

Comment: It might be a path problem. Try: `restoredefaultpath`. Check if the toolbox in the path. In my machine: `find(contains(path, 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019a\toolbox\comm\comm'))
`

Comment: I searched for communication toolbox in Add-Ons manager ,it is not installed. I install it and the code is run. Thank you very much.